# How to prohibit some words and letters to use as a Drupal password?

Tags: forms

I need to prohibit a user from using a few words as a password. E.g I don't want to use these words as a password. Drupal, 123456, Microsoft. When a user submits the registration form with the above terms in the password field then they get a message about the prohibited password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This module should work. I have never used it before, but it should definitely have the feature to prohibit certain password strings. 
[Password Policy Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider the [Password Strength](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_strength) module. Some details about it (from its project page):

> ... provides realistic password strength measurement and server-side enforcement for Drupal sites using pattern-matching and entropy calculation. Almost any type of password can be allowed so long as the password proves to be of high enough entropy. For inspiration see the [XKCD comic on password strength](http://xkcd.com/936/).

PS: Here is how the linked comic looks like:

[image]